# What does the "m" stand for in java code

Tags: java, android

What does the "m" mean when it is put as a prefix before a word in android programming particularly in android java class files? I have lately been seeing it a lot in my generated main activity. Where can you use "m" as a prefix for statements/terms in programming?
Like in the examples below:

```
mUserLearnedDrawer
mCurrentSelectedPosition
mFromSavedInstanceState
mUserLearnedDrawer
```

Comment: It's a convention to have a distinction between member variables of a class  and parameters (like in a constructor)

Comment: Its for people who do not have a powerful integrated development environment that automatically displays member variables in a different color. To compensate for not having a different color, they use a different name.

Comment: Too bad this has been closed. Anyway, this style is called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation
It was useful in earlier times; but in the year 2015, with IDEs that now anything about your source code, it should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @EddyG why should it be avoided ?

Comment: @EddyG why should it be avoided? Google uses it alot. `GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;`, with buttons, etc

Comment: It is a matter of personal taste. Without an IDE, it was sometimes really hard to figure (easily) where a variable is coming from. Nowadays, all decent IDEs provide such information directly. 
In that sense - information that is not required can be seen as WASTE; and therefore it is fair to discuss avoiding it.
I have been using such notation for 10+ years plus; and we decided to not do it in our new project - and I don't miss it at all. Because the IDE can tell me anything I need to know.
And googles coding standard is googles coding standard; not mine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Letter m as prefix means that it is member of class.
Letters lv means that it is local variable.
Letters pm means that it is parameter.

example:

```
class Example
{
  Integer mMemberOfClass;

  public void someMethod(Object pmSomeParameter)
  {
    Integer lvSomeLocalVariable;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply it means this variable is member of the class.